# restart frequency for :simple_one_for_one worker

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

How can i set the restart frequency, when creating wokers dynamically? In the current setup, the worker keeps restarting for infinity.

I've also tried setting :max_restarts, inside the worker spec(worker(Kombiner.Foo, [], max_restarts: 3, max_seconds: 5))
and it seems it doesn't do anything at all(it will keep restarting for infinity).

```
def start_child(input) do
  Supervisor.start_child(@name, [input])
end


def init(:ok) do
  children = [
    worker(Kombiner.Foo, [], restart: :transient)
  ]
  supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
end
```

inside the Kombiner.Foo worker:

```
def handle_info({any, :timeout}, _state) do
  {:stop, :timeout, nil}
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max_restarts: 3, max_seconds: 5` needs to be added to the `supervise/2` call at the end of `init/1`, not the `worker/3` function called in the list of children. Your code should look like this:

```
def init(:ok) do
  children = [
    worker(Kombiner.Foo, [], restart: :transient)
  ]
  supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one, max_restarts: 3, max_seconds: 5)
end
```

The restart strategy, max restarts, and max seconds pertain to all the children in the list.

For more info, see [the Supervisor.Spec.supervise/2 documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html#//apple_ref/Function/supervise%2F2).

Comment: actually, i did tried to add max_restart and max_seconds to the supervise/2 function but the main problem was that i had like 3 restarts in like 10 seconds so the frequency didn't match - i should try to understand the docs better, next time - thank you!